# Как увеличить размер картинки ImageList больше 256x256?

Tags: c#, winforms, изображения, picturebox

Как увеличить размер картинки imagelist ImageList больше 256;256 256x256?

У меня есть ноты для пианино, которые я загружаю в imagelist ImageList они становится 256;256 256x256 и выглядит это не очень красиво.
Можно

Можно ли увеличить размер в imagelist ImageList или где хранить изображения, что бы они не теряли свой размер при вставке picterbox PictureBox?

```
// Display the image.
    private void button52_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (imageList1.Images.Empty != true)
            {
                if (imageList1.Images.Count - 1 > currentImage)
                {
                    currentImage++;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentImage = 0;
                }


                // Show the image in the PictureBox.
                pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[currentImage];

                listBox1.SelectedIndex = currentImage;

            }
    }

    // Remove the image.
    private void button54_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imageList1.Images.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
        listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
    }
    // Clear all images.
    private void button56_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imageList1.Images.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
    }

    // Find an image.
    private void button58_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.FileNames != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < openFileDialog1.FileNames.Length; i++)
                {
                    addImage(openFileDialog1.FileNames[i]);
                }
            }
            else
                addImage(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
    }
    private void addImage(string imageToLoad)
    {
        if (imageToLoad != "")
        {
            imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(imageToLoad));
            listBox1.BeginUpdate();
            listBox1.Items.Add(imageToLoad);
            listBox1.EndUpdate();
        }
    }
```

[image: piano]

Comment: Используйте любую подходящую коллекцию. Например, `List<Image>`.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov можете пример привести пожалуйста